# How to send 100,000+ files as ArrayList<String> in Intent().putExtra?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to pass an ArrayList() from one Intent to another Intent.
Sometimes the size of the array will be more than 100,000. Pass such a huge array in android will throw a runtime exception. Is there any alternative to solve this issue?

Here is the code from sending Intent:

```
var image = ArrayList<File>()

// getAllImages() returns all image present in the device as an `ArrayList<File>`

image.addAll(getAllImages()) // add all image present in the device. Sometimes size of image will be more than 100,000
try{
     val intent = Intent(applicationContext, Slider::class.java) // Slider is the receiving Intent
         intent.apply {
         putExtra("position", position) // sends position of selected image
         putExtra("arrayList", convertfile(image)) // convertfile(image) returns ArrayList<File> as ArrayList<String>
         flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
         }
         startActivity(intent)

} catch (rx: java.lang.RuntimeException) {

}
```

Code for convertfile() :

```
fun convertfile(file: java.util.ArrayList<File>) : java.util.ArrayList<String> {
var temp: String

val string = java.util.ArrayList<String>()
for (j in file.indices) {
    temp = file[j].path
    string.add(temp)
}
return string
}
```

Code for receiving Intent :

```
 val position: Int  = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0)
 val file: ArrayList<String> = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("arrayList") as ArrayList<String>
```

When the size of `image` is like 100,000 android throws a runtime exception. How to solve this issue? Is there any alternative solution to pass huge array between two intents?

Comment: Use one activity and two fragments instead of two activities. Or, use a singleton repository that manages your data, where each of your activities gets the data from that repository.

Comment: This is just bad programming practice. Why on earth would you want to do this? You have an architectural flaw here, not a technical problem.